# Is the correct way for adding the author's name on Facebook Sharing to use: meta name="author"

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, author

In some Facebook posts I see the author of the page, beyond the title and description. For example, in the image below is the string "Di Redazione":

[image]

Looking at the source code of the page:

```
http://www.tuttonotizie.info/notizie1/ultime-notizie-di/politica/25340-borghi-ai-sindaci-protagonisti-nel-processo-di-nascita-delle-unioni.html
```

I have seen that the author it is written with the string:

```
<meta name="author" content="Redazione" />
```

Is this the correct way to do this, or is there some other way? Searching Google didn't provide a thorough enough answer.

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24920353/1591669) on [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think best practise would be to use the open graph tag 'article:author', which links to your facebook profile.  This is how Facebook ask you to declare an author.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article

Generally, when you use the Open Graph Debugger, warning messages are along the lines of "The 'og:NAME' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.".

I imagine this is the same for the author tag - they will use the old `meta name=author` if they cannot find their own tag.

Comment: Yes, but the article:author doesn't work as the image above, it adds a link to follow the author of the article. If meta name author is obsolete why Facebook supports it in that way?

Comment: It's not actually an obsolete tag, but I'm surprised Facebook don't appear to mention using it.

Comment: So it is right to use it to achieve the result in the image above?

Comment: It certainly *works* (for a short name, anyway), as I've done it that way myself, and it is a good idea to have that meta tag on your site regardless.  As Facebook don't seem to promote it anywhere, or offer an exact OG alternative, I would question how long it is likely to remain a feature, however.